# Does iPhone/iPad Safari require 'Accept-Ranges' header for video?

Tags: ipad, html, http, mobile-safari, html5-video

I've been having problems serving videos from my dev server that play in mobile Safari.  My dev server does not support the 'Accept-Ranges' header and after reading a few forums I've discovered that may be my problem.  [Here is an example forum posting saying just that.](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonewebdev/browse_thread/thread/794c4b5cb6d59768/c4073c261ab43d18?pli=1)

Is this correct?  Does mobile Safari require the Accept-Ranges header?  Can anyone point me to any Apple documentation actually stating that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found some Apple documentation that says that it does in fact need that for video.

> **HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range**
>   requests, which iOS uses to perform random access in media playback.
>   (Byte-range support is also known as content-range or partial-range
>   support.) Most, but not all, HTTP 1.1 servers already support
>   byte-range requests.
>
> If you are not sure whether your media server supports byte-range
>   requests, you can open the Terminal application in OS X and use the
>   curl command-line tool to download a short segment from a file on the
>   server:
>
> `curl --range 0-99 http://example.com/test.mov -o /dev/null`
>
> If the tool reports that it downloaded 100 bytes, the media server correctly
>   handled the byte-range request. If it downloads the entire file, you
>   may need to update the media server.

[Source: Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762072/1985033) is helpful, but does not actually answer the question that was asked.

According to the [HTTP RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7233), the Accept-Ranges header is optional even when byte-range requests are supported.

However, the documented curl check implies that the answer is **no**: iOS does not require the Accept-Ranges header for video, but does require byte-range support with partial content (206) responses.

Disclaimer: I haven't checked it on an actual device.

Comment: I have checked it on several actual devices - if I disable byte-range support on my server, any Safari browser will refuse to play the video.

Comment: I think that part has already been established, but the question is whether it requires Accept-Ranges headers (which are not required by the RFC in order for byte-range requests to work).

Comment: I was trying to help you out with actual device tests, but OK.

Comment: Thanks! If there's a way to test the second part (with byte ranges and with/without accept-ranges headers), then we'll have the definitive answer.