# Serving mp4 video to iPad

Tags: ipad, video, mp4

I want to serve a mp4 video in a HTML document but it doesn't play on the live server. Locally it works.

Even using only the file without any HTML it does play when I use my local Apache. On the webserver the iPad says "Movie could not be played"

The header for the file is "video/mp4" on both Servers.

What could be the problem here?

Regards

UPDATE:

Header local Apache:

> Accept-Ranges    bytes
>   Cache-Control    max-age=86400
>   Connection    Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length    8993646
>   Content-Type    video/mp4
>   Date    Thu, 23 Feb 2012 14:40:58 GMT
>   Etag    "733258-893b6e-36d96c80"
>   Keep-Alive    timeout=15, max=100
>   Last-Modified    Thu, 23 Feb 2012 10:36:18 GMT

Header live server:

> Cache-Control    max-age=86400
>   Connection    Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length    8993670
>   Content-Type    video/mp4
>   Date    Thu, 23 Feb 2012 14:40:40 GMT
>   Keep-Alive    timeout=15, max=100
>   Server    Apache
>   X-Mod-H264-Streaming    version=2.0

What's also weird is that the Content-Length differs from local to live...

Comment: Does it work on a computer, or does it not work only in iPad? How do you play the movie on a local Apache with an iPad?

Comment: @Juhana it works on the computer in all browsers, just not on the ipad when served from the live machine

Comment: Can you tell us the encoding settings of your mp4 file. Here is standard ipad encoding settings for mp4 files. http://www.encoding.com/ipad_streaming_template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is a wrong `Conten-Length` header from the live-server. After fixing this problem it worked.

Collegue fixed server settings, so I don't know excactly what he did. Just that the lenght is now the same as on my local machine

Answer (score 3):

Check what the live server is sending out for a mime header v.s. what your local one is. The live server may be sending `application/octet-stream` (or some other default type) instead of `video/mp4`. Browsers go by the supplied mime-type in the response headers for the most part, not the served up file extension.

Comment: response header is video/mp4 on both, what else header could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HTML5  along with a mp4 file. There should be no problems playing the file on your iPad.. the only thing left is to make sure the link is not broken and add this part to make further testing :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag. //add this line
</video>
```

Comment: please read again sentence two... it DOES play with local webserver... but doesn't on the live machine...

Answer (score 0):

The web server serving the media files should also support 'Accept-Ranges' header. This is mentioned in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397241/does-iphone-ipad-safari-require-accept-ranges-header-for-video) which has a link to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6).