# How to serve video files to the ipad using jetty/ring

Tags: clojure, jetty, ring

I have set up a simple ring server with a file server

```
(ns scratch.basic-test
  (:use [ring.middleware.file :only [wrap-file]]
        [ring.middleware.file-info :only [wrap-file-info]])
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]))

(defn naked-handler [request]
  {:status 200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
   :body (str request})

(defonce server 
  (run-jetty (-> #'naked-handler
                 (wrap-file "resources/public")
                 wrap-file-info)               
             {:port 8890 :join? false}))
```

I have `test.mp4` and `video.html` in the `resources/public` directory.

---

`video.html` references the mp4 file:

```
  ...blah...
  <video id="my_video_1" controls>
     <source src="test.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
   </video>
  ...blah...
```

---

when I open up `http://server-ip-address:8890/video.html` in safari, firefox and ie it works fine

however, when i open it up on the ipad, it does not.. a black cannot-play-rectangle is displayed instead.

---

when i put the same files in an apache server and open up video.html on the ipad the video plays perfectly....

what is going on?

Comment: Could you try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415050/serving-mp4-video-to-ipad

Comment: i'm not sure how to do this in jetty

Answer (score 1):

I'll reply here as comment section is too tight for to my taste :).

I think before changing anything it makes sense to take a look at the HTML headers. Compare what Apache gives you against ring. It could be that issue is related to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415050/serving-mp4-video-to-ipad) or maybe it's something else. If you don't know how to see the header [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374100/how-to-debug-the-http-response-headers-from-a-http-call) might help.

As for modifying header I think if anything has to be modified it will be on the ring level not Jetty.

I ran your application here are headers:

```
Name    Value
Date    Wed, 12 Sep 2012 05:26:20 GMT
Content-Length  36320472
Last-Modified   Sat, 12 May 2012 21:04:47 +0000
Server  Jetty(7.6.1.v20120215)
Content-Type    video/mp4;charset=UTF-8
```

It played in Chrome, sorry I don't have an iPad to check it. Content length is correct it is equal to the original mp4 file size.

I guess unless you post headers from both servers there's nothing else I can do.

Comment: thanks. just wondering... why do the headers get messed up like that?

Comment: I posted header from Clojure server.