# MP4 doesn't play after initial load in Safari

Tags: html, safari

I have embedded a [mp4 file](https://wao.io/45378fcb3a22dd7d57af76822ab07e54.mp4) in my webpage, that gets loaded fine and is playable by every browser and on mobile too.

```
<video controls src="/mymovie.mp4">
  <track kind="captions"></track>
</video>
```

However, when I open the webpage with Safari (macOS), the only thing I can see is a black box with the size of the video and a striked through (disabled) play button in front of it. The thing is, when I refresh the page again (even without clearing the cache) the video works fine.

[image]

When I write my markup to use the `source` element, the problem appears, but in a different way. Now I see no longer a black box, but a transparent one and I can press the play button, but the video won't start. I already tried to place a "*not supported*" text under the `source` list, but the text doesn't appear.

```
<video controls>
  <track kind="captions"></track>
  <source src="/mymovie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  not supported
</video>
```

*Notice that I already tried reordering the `source` element above the `track` element.*

Is there any known problem of this kind and a way to solve it?

Here are some more informations about my setup:

- HTTPS only (valid certificate)
- video size is around 3,5MB
- NGINX is configured to send this headers:

  - `accept-ranges: bytes`
  - `Content-Range: bytes 262144-3411398/3411399`
  - `content-type: video/mp4`

Something I notice in difference to Chrome is, that inside my devtools network tab the video source is loaded between 2 and 4 times, but just one time of it with the correct size. The other two entries are just some bytes. However, this happens in the same way, if I face the black box.

Comment: check this it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199261/why-wont-safari-play-file-without-extension-in-video/51901198#51901198

Comment: And this one too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712778/video-plays-in-other-browsers-but-not-safari

Comment: Yeah! The first link seems definitely to be useful. I will check some things out. Thank you!

Comment: happy to hear that :). wish u the best. I can search with you more till we find solution. let me know.

Comment: could it be possible for you to upload the mp4 somewhere so that it can be downloaded and tested? also which version of Safari is it?

Comment: I linked a video into the question: https://wao.io/45378fcb3a22dd7d57af76822ab07e54.mp4

Answer (score 1):

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="/mymovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="captions"></track>
</video>
```

Did you try using `source` tag instead? `Autoplay` attribute can also help, but **some browsers do not allow videos to be autoplayed, or autoplay all videos as muted, if user didn't interract with document first**. My best guess is that Safari doesn't allow to play a video without the prior interaction, and you refreshing the page do interact with the page. You can *cheat* it playing video after clicking on *privacy policy* accept button.

```
// jQuery
$('#button-id').click(function(){ $('#video-id').play(); });

// Javascript
var button = document.getElementById('button-id');
var video = document.getElementById('video-id');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){ video.play(); });
```

Comment: I don't want to autoplay the video, but I will try the `source` element. Thank you!

Comment: I found some interesting news with the `source` approach. I've edited my question.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. Did you try using another .mp4 file? Maybe encoding is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely possible. But wouldn't that disable the video **always**?

Answer (score 1):

If your video is in the same folder you should use:

```
    <video controls autoplay>
    <source src="mymovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="captions"></track>
your browser doesn't support HTML5 video
</video>
```

or

```
    <video controls autoplay>
    <source src="./mymovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="captions"></track>
your browser doesn't support HTML5 video
</video>
```

You could also include your whole url:

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://url.to/mymovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="captions"></track>
your browser doesn't support HTML5 video
</video>
```