# Streaming video from S3 with Express/NodeJS to play in Safari

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, safari, html5-video

I am using SSE-C encryption for S3 files, so when playing back the video, I am forwarding the request to S3 through the server by attaching params correctly.

```
export default async function(req, res) {
  const {userid, fileid} = req.params;
  console.log(userid, fileid);
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `users/${userid}/notes/${fileid}`,
    SSECustomerKey: process.env.AWS_SSE_KEY,
    SSECustomerAlgorithm: "AES256"
  };

  s3.getObject(params)
    .on("httpHeaders", function(statusCode, headers) {
      console.log(headers);
      res.set("Content-Length", headers["content-length"]);
      res.set("Content-Type", headers["content-type"]);
      res.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
      this.response.httpResponse.createUnbufferedStream().pipe(res);
    })
    .send();
}
```

While this works fine with HTML5 video tag in Chrome/Firefox, it doesn't work in Safari because return `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream` (found a similar question [Why won't Safari play file without extension in <video>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199261/why-wont-safari-play-file-without-extension-in-video))

I have tried resetting the `Content-Type` manually to a correct `video/quicktime` or `video/mp4` depending on a file, but that doesn't help.

I have also tried setting `Content-Ranges` manually, but that information doesn't get returned from S3 (or I am missing something), so that didn't help either.

Is this even possible to achieve? What am I missing?

Comment: Check it: https://blog.logrocket.com/streaming-video-in-safari/