# MP4 files not playing in Safari (desktop and IOS) event if Range header is correctly defined

Tags: ios, video, safari, http-headers, apache-cocoon

Since many days, I'm trying to load this link: http://test-v4.pleade.com:8205/pleade/functions/ead/detached/docs/test.mp4 It doesn't work in Safari (Desktop and IOS devices)

According to this thread: [Why won't Safari play file without extension in <video>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199261/why-wont-safari-play-file-without-extension-in-video/51901198#51901198) (and many others), you can notice that HTTP headers (Ranges, Content-Length, ...) are correctly defined in my case.

When you check the "request response flow", you can noticed that the first request, where Safari test the compatibility with Range (Byte Range 0-1) is correctly processed. But, It stops at that point. Safari refuses to throw next parts where he asks the MP4 file bytes per bytes.

I'm working with Tomcat and Apache Cocoon. For being sure to avoid encode problems, I have tried the same mp4 file directly and only with an Apache Server. It is loaded well in Safari and all other browsers (direct link here: http://test-v4.pleade.com/test.mp4).

Thank you for you helps.

Comment: I am also having this issue. Any luck solving it over the past couple months?