# Need to Set Range in Requestheader in Apache Confiuration file

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

My videos are not working in Safari browser, I have checked many links regarding this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199261/why-wont-safari-play-file-without-extension-in-video/51901198#51901198)

and others as well but nowhere is a particular way for implementation this in Apache configuration file httpd.conf for every type of content on the site.

I resolved it by adding the below code in httpd.conf

**RequestHeader set Range: bytes=0-1**

But the other site CSS stopped working.

How can I set Range for all type of contents?

My website code is in PHP.

No idea, if it is a wrong question about this?

Please help with this.

Comment: Can someone please help here or we are here just for ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why - points are here but I got the issue resolved by adding the below code in the **.htaccess** file:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)bytes=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L,E=0-1:%2]

RequestHeader set Range "bytes=%{0-1}e" env=range

</IfModule>
```

Thanks.